# -I effect vs +M effect of Chlorine on acidity of benzoic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, carboxylic-acids

The -I power of Halogens like Chlorine is stronger than their +M power. Therefore, we consider -I effect for comparing acidity of benzoic acid [Ka-> ortho > meta > para]. But shouldn't -I effect be weaker in para-chloro benzoic acid, it will pull electrons, from the ring, but not so much directly from -COOH. On the other hand, the +M power will be same as it is range independent.

[image][image]

Using the above example to emphasize on the point, the -I power on -COOH will be extremely weaker than the +M power. Chlorine would pull electrons from the attached ring, but not so much from -COOH group and its +M effect should make it less acidic.

So why do we always take halogens like chlorines to be always electron withdrawing group?

Which structure is more acidic? The left one will have +M effect but stronger -I, right one will have no +M effect but sligthly worse -I effect